# Black vertical lines all over the screen my MacBook Air

Tags: mac, display, hardware, screen

**How the issue occurred:**

I was just watching YouTube and all of a sudden I have black vertical lines all over my screen.

- macOS: Sierra
- MacBook Air 2017

[image: Blurred display with black vertical lines]

**What I tried :**

- Force shutdown and restart.
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

**Question**

- Will any external monitor help me in this case? ( As I will not be able to update any settings.)
- What could be the cause? (Heat only or something?)
- Is there any way to recover it or will have to go to a high-end store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it looks like a hardware issue. You'll need to take it to an Apple Store or other Apple-authorised technician.

If it is a new Mac, then you may be able to get a free repair (or replacement). The age for which this will apply varies depending on local laws.

If it is an older Mac, you will have to pay for the repair, and you will need to decide whether the cost is worth it, or if you are better off putting it towards a new(er) Mac.

If it is a *very* old Mac, then you could try a "non-high-end" repair shop, though realistically, they would have to use secondhand replacement parts (e.g. the logic board) as Apple doesn't sell parts. This might be cheaper, but there's no guarantee that it will last.

You may be able to use the MBA with an external display (depending on the nature of the fault). It's worth testing before you buy a display. Obviously, you lose the portability.

Oh, and don't forget to backup your files before giving it to repair.

Comment: Update : Thanks @benwiggy I was able to recover my data using an external monitor... now have to run diagnostics before taking it to a technician (mp it is a hardware problem (screen replacement will be sufficient ) but will have to figure out the root cause.)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely looks like a hardware issue. I honestly don't think a system wipe will do anything. It may be worth a shot once you eliminate hardware issues though.

If it is purely a hardware issue than connecting to an external monitor should allow you to use the MacBook.

Comment: A wipe is "always worth a shot"?  I would think it is the last thing you try, not the first.

Comment: Never said it's the first thing you try, I said "I honestly don't think a system wipe will do anything" with any common sense you would figure that would be the last option.

Comment: "I honestly don't think a system wipe will do anything but it's always worth a shot" is the *first* thing that you suggested, in your original (unedited) answer.

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable responses.. so I just tried everything... Also added an external monitor ( it's working )

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/401322/how-can-i-reinstall-macos-without-a-working-display and https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5163539

Comment: Thanks @lhf definitely I will try these... Thank you 

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what I did ( as I did multiple things I don't remember ) ... Finally it's back again  I'm in shock too [MP This is a heat issue/ poorly charged and will come back if it's not taken care of. ] ..[image: my current working pc]